# How to compare query results for multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables, User, AccessControlKey and AccessControlGroup. User can be assigned to multiple products. AccessControlKeys can be assigned to multiple AccessControlGroups. However a User cannot have AccessControlKey assigned to him more than once i.e. for a User across the multiple AccessControlGroups assigned to him, AccessControlKey has to be unique across the AccessContolGroups assigned to him.

For the many to many relationships between accesscontrolkeys and user and for many to many relationship between accesscontrolkeys and accesscontrolgroups i have two separate tables.  Following is the table descriptions for the 3 tables and the relationship mapping table. How do i enforce the unique AccessControlKey across multiple AccessControlGroup for a User?

http://pastebin.com/EzL9QUGg

Comment: Please edit your question and include the table layouts.  Text descriptions of tables are easier to understand than pictures.

Comment: Also, put the code from pastebin here. Links can broken then your question will be useless.

Comment: The question title does not really relate to the question.. I suggest it should be more along the lines of 'Enforcing unique constraint across multiple tables'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, I'm guessing that each `User` has one `AccessControlKey` and the key can belong to multiple `AccessControlGroup`s.

I'd probably change the data structure and change your `User_BelongsTo_AccessControlGroup` to a `User_AccessControlKey` (linking a `User` to an `AccessControlKey`) instead; you can enforce the uniqueness here. You can still get to the `User`'s `AccessControlGroup`s through this table and the `AccessControlKey_BelongsTo_AccessControlGroup`.